# Не работает обратная анимация

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

На [странице](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/test4_links2/) не работает эффект анимации при отводе курсора от ссылки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста, как-нибудь организовывайте код так, чтобы другим было удобно его править :)

http://jsfiddle.net/GdKJu/1/

```
function animationStart(){          
    console.log('start');
    $self.find('.lnkOld').stop().animate({'marginLeft': '-=' + width}, 1000);
}

function animationStop(){
    console.log('stop');
    var lnkold =  $self.find('.lnkOld');
    lnkold.stop().animate({'marginLeft': '-=' + lnkold.css('margin-left')}, 1000, function() {
        removeLink();
    });
}
```

В общем вся суть в том, что у вас было:

```
$self.find('.lnkOld').animate({'marginLeft': '+=' + width}, 1000, removeLink());
```

Функция `removeLink()` вызывалась сразу, т.к. оператор вызова - это круглые скобки.

Comment: спасибо. невнимательность подвела)